# Problem 'Route not found' in Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I try to explain myself better. I encountered the problem in the address of the route for the creation of a generic resource in the Laravel framework, I take as an example the creation of a product and its modification.

```
    Route::post('/product/create/', [
        \App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'product_create'
    ])->name('product.create');

    Route::patch('/product-{productId}/edit/', [
        \App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'product_edit'
    ])->name('product.edit');
```

Instead of two routes, one for editing and one for creating, I want to use a single save route. Obviously the wildcare productId parameter must be optional.

```
   Route::post('/product-{productId?}/save/', [
        \App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'product_save'
    ])->name('product.save');
```

The problem persists in creating a product because the URL becomes

```
/product-/save/
```

Is there a way to make the (-) optional in the case of saving a product and have it stay in the edit so that everything works correctly?
Is there a way to make the (-) optional in the case of saving a product and have it stay in the edit so that everything works correctly?

Comment: Why would you want `productId` to be optional in the save route? If you're not passing an ID of the product to save, what are you trying to save? There should be separate methods for handling the create submission and edit submission. Also, the route should really be like `/product/{productId}/edit` (or `/save`) to match with conventions. Maybe consider using a proper Resource Controller: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: We would like to use the same controller for creation and editing, and limit the total number of routes in the project. Is there any way to put the optional (-)?
My 'product_save' route should look like this `/product-1/save/` and  `/product/save/` as appropriate
     @TimLevis

Comment: Unless you make the `-` part of the variable name, I don't think this is possible since Laravel directly matches the visited routes to your defined routes. Why would you need to limit the amount of routes anyway, if it leads to more complicated controller and route logic? Use a resource controller, paired with the `Route::resource` method to cut down on the amount of route definitions in your `web.php` file.

Comment: Not really, as optional URL parameters don't work well in the middle of a Route like that. Pass it as a `POST` parameter, like `if ($request->input('action') == 'create')` vs `if ($request->input('action') == 'update')`, or pass a `product_id` like that `if ($request->input('product_id', null) { // Logic to update } else { // Logic to create }`, etc etc.

Comment: The problem is that saving the new one and modifying it do the "same thing", the views are identical and the controller is consequently "the same":

`$ product = Product :: find ('productId'); // edit`
`$ product = new Product; // create new`

Continuous is the same ...       

do you think it is still better to create two separate controllers that do the same thing? maybe use a service?

Comment: You can declare 2 routes pointing to the same controller method.